# Install PostgreSQL when data folder already exists

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgis-installation

1. A few days ago my hard drive stop working but I was able to retrieve most of the information. I had PostgreSQL 10 installed with several databases.
2. I have installed PostgreSQL in my new hard drive (Windows 10) and I have the data folder from my previous hard drive in an external drive.
3. In the installation I selected the old data folder as the current data folder, but keeping it in the external drive. When I start pgadmin 4 I can see all the databases I had just fine.
4. When I try to retrieve information from a table pgadmin 4 shows the following message: > ERROR:  could no access file «$libdir/postgis-2.4»: No such file or directory
   SQL state: 58P01
5. I can't find the bundle for postgis version 2.4, and I've installed postgis 3 but it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me where to find the postgis 2.4 bundle for windows or if there is a way to import postgis from my old installation in the other hard drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I installed the bundle for version 2.4.4 and it worked fine. The problem was that I had installed postgis 3.0 before.